# Reading data between markers in R

Tags: r, file-io

What is the best way to read a CSV file into R when there are 3 data markers? To obtain the indexes for the start and end markers then get the data between these markers only. Save the new data in separate data frames and then name each variable using the data marker?

Human activity data sample

```
576 -2404   6556  12512  30.74  3788  -2249
577 -1428  10020  13024  30.69  2308  -1852
..
..
Sample aX  aY az Temp gX gY gz
554  375   2648   7412  13612  30.18  -286   -288  
..
..
Sample aX  aY az Temp gX gY gz
1 -1844 10224 11768 30.69 -332 -387 -62
2 -1876 10192 11708 30.65 -297 -435 -21
3 -1804 10332 11692 30.74 -355 -265 -78
..
..
Sample aX  aY az Temp gX gY gz
1068  375   2648   7412  13612  30.18  -286   -288  
1069  376   276
..
..
```

How to achieve any guidance/direction or kindly refer be to any material which will be helpful/beneficial or help me out to complete the task.

Answer (score 0):

Given the following csv

[image]

```
#read in data as is
data_raw <- readLines("./test.csv")
# find separation lines:
from <- which(grepl("^Sample", data_raw))
to   <- c(from[2:length(from)] - 1, length(data_raw))
# create cuncks to read
L <- lapply(seq.int(length(from)), 
            function(i) paste0(data_raw[from[i]:to[i]], 
                               collapse = "\n"))
# read
lapply(L, data.table::fread)
# [[1]]
#    Sample  aX   aY   az  Temp    gX   gY   gz
# 1:    554 375 2648 7412 13612 30.18 -286 -288
# 
# [[2]]
#    Sample    aX    aY    az  Temp   gX   gY  gz
# 1:      1 -1844 10224 11768 30.69 -332 -387 -62
# 2:      2 -1876 10192 11708 30.65 -297 -435 -21
# 3:      3 -1804 10332 11692 30.74 -355 -265 -78
# 
# [[3]]
#    Sample  aX   aY   az  Temp    gX   gY   gz
# 1:   1068 375 2648 7412 13612 30.18 -286 -288
```